# What is the sum of this series: $1 + \frac{1}{5}x + \frac{1 \times 6}{5 \times 10}x^2 +\cdots$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form

Say I have a series like the following;

> $$1 + \frac{1}{5}x + \frac{1 \times 6}{5 \times 10}x^2 + \frac{1 \times 6 \times 11}{5 \times 10 \times 15}x^3 + \cdots.$$

How do I find the sum of this?
I'm trying to find an expression for the nth term but struggling!

Comment: Well, it may help to know how the series is defined. Whence does the expression above come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jennifer answered, the general term seems to be 
$$
\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (5i+1) }{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} 5(i+1)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac15+n\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac15\right)\Gamma\left(n+1\right)}=\frac{\left(\frac15\right)_n}{n!} \tag1
$$ where $(x)_n=x(x+1)\cdots (x+n-1)$, then one may recall the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalisations),
$$
\left(1-x \right)^{-\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\alpha\right)_n}{n!}x^n.
\tag2$$ Hence, by putting $\alpha=\dfrac15$ in $(2)$, one gets, using $(1)$:

> $$
> 1 + \frac{1}{5}x + \frac{1 \times 6}{5 \times 10}x^2 + \frac{1 \times 6 \times 11}{5 \times 10 \times 15}x^3 + \cdots =\color{red}{\frac1{(1-x)^{1/5}}}, \quad |x|<1. \tag3
> $$

Answer (score 0):

The term for $x^n$ seems to be :
$$\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (5i+1) }{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} 5(i+1)} $$